# How can I handle exception in catch block in c++

Tags: c++, exception

say I have code

```
try
{
   .... 
}
catch()
{
   .... // exception occur here ... how to handled. 
}
```

Is there any mechanism in c++ by which the above scenario can be handled.

Comment: Wrap it in a `try`/`catch`...?

Comment: By making sure that you don't have any code that can throw an exception in the exception handler?

Comment: The above comment might sound like a joke, but it is dead serious.

Comment: If you don't know what to do with the exception, let your caller handle it.

Comment: If there's a need to do thing like that then it shows flaw in your deign

Comment: Yes, there are several mechanisms. You can put a `try` inside the `catch` block, you can nest `try` blocks, you can use a re-throw (`throw;` with no subexpression), you can save an `exception_ptr`, you can use `nested_exception`. We need more info to guide you in a particular direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think this is what you really want, you can do it like this:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        //...
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        //...
        if( .. )
            throw std::runtime_exception( "error occured" );
    }
}
catch( std::runtime_exception& e )
{
    // handle exception of exception handler
}
```

Comment: I am also thinking of same but ... dont know whether this is the best way to anything else can also be done ... ?

Comment: @Nihar: You could also put a try-catch block into the `catch( ... )`-body: `try{ } catch( ... ){ try{ } catch( ... ) }`